# how to set action-outputs as defined in action.yml from a bash-script

Tags: github-actions

I have an `action.yml` file with outputs:

```
name: My action
description: executes bash script
inputs:
 some_input:
    description: some input
    required: true
outputs:
  some_output:
    description: some output
runs:
  using: node12
  main: dist/index.js
```

This action is a node action that only executes a bash script. I want to give this action some input and the bash script to give some output.

index.js:

```
const core = require("@actions/core");
const exec = require("@actions/exec");

async function run() {
  try {
    const someInput = core.getInput('some_input');
    await exec.exec(`bash ${__dirname}/some-bash-script.sh ${someInput}`);
  } catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message);
  }
}

run();
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo ::set-output name=some_output="My output ($1)"
```

Workflow yaml:

```
name: maven deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

jobs:

  mine:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: jactor-rises/my-action@v1
        id: mine
        with:
          some_input: this input
      - run: echo ${{ steps.mine.outputs.some_output }}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? It does not work in my workflow... How do I use this output in my workflow?

This question is answered on GitHub, but I am still struggeling: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-set-action-output-as-defined-in-action-yml-from-a-bash/m-p/50366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bash script is trying to echo an environment variable `INPUT_SOME_INPUT`.  That environment variable is not being set.

Your action is passing its input to the shell script (`someInput`) as the first argument.  You need to either:

1. set an environment variable `INPUT_SOME_INPUT` instead, or
2. use the first argument in the bash script (`$1`).

For example:

```
echo ::set-output name=some_output="My output ($1)"
```

Comment: sorry... I forgot to edit this on my post, you can see The GitHub forum for more details...